# how can i convert this a href link into a button?

Tags: html

```
echo "<a href=User_list.php?id=$row[1]&sec=$row[5]&subj=$row[6]&type=viewrec2&Year=$row[12]&faci=$row[9]>LIST</a></td>";
```

how can i convert this code into a button? and make the button as an image button that i made.

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot understand your question: Which code? and: Do you want to add an image to your button?

Comment: Don’t forget to escape the `&`.

Comment: And, indeed, escape/URL-encode the characters in the $row[] variables. Then again, we keep complaining about the HTML and SQL injections and seniorprojectdiva keeps on posting the same broken code, so what can you do?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
echo "<form action=\"User_list.php?id=$row[1]&sec=$row[5]&subj=$row[6]&type=viewrec2&Year=$row[12]&faci=$row[9]\">";
echo "  <button type=\"submit\" value=\"LIST\">";
echo "    <img src=\"image.gif\" alt=\"LIST\"/>";
echo "  </button>";
echo "</form>";
```

(Thanks to @guerda for [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601769/how-can-i-convert-this-a-href-link-into-a-button/601779#601779) on how to include the image.)

You'll have to escape the `'&'` characters, but I don't know how you do it in PHP.

Note that this can have a side effect if you have other forms in the same page.

Comment: You're welcome. :) Good example for the wiki style answering: First person gives an idea, second person uses it and it's the perfect answer :)

Comment: To write out '&amp;' in PHP, you just write out '&amp;'.  What's the difficulty?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.location = 'User_list.php?id=$row[1]&sec=$row[5]&subj=$row[6]&type=viewrec2&Year=$row[12]&faci=$row[9]'" class="myButton" />
```

You can use CSS to style your button's background image accordingly

Comment: I first thought about this, but it won't work when JavaScript is disabled.

Answer (score 2):

To add an image to a HTML form button, try this:

```
<button name="somebutton" type="button" value="somevalue" onclick="alert('Hello World!');">
  <img src="someimage.gif" alt="someimage">
</button>
```

From: [SelfHTML (German)](http://de.selfhtml.org/html/formulare/klickbuttons.htm)